# Get occurrence count in nested map

Tags: groovy

How to get the number of occurrence in a complex map?

eg.

```
def a = [  CRQ1:[STATUS: "Scheduled"], CRQ1:[STATUS: "Draft"]  ]
```

I need to get the STATUS Occurrence here

```
a.CRQ1.STATUS.size()
```

Expected Output: 2

Actual Output: 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map there contains two times the same key:

```
groovy:000> a = [CRQ1:[STATUS: "Scheduled"], CRQ1:[STATUS: "Draft"]]
===> [CRQ1:[STATUS:Draft]]
groovy:000> a.CRQ1.STATUS.size()
===> 5
```

(note that `.size()` here returns the string length of the word *Draft*)

Errors like this are easier to catch, if you explicitly use the spread operator, if you intend to call functions on all elements.  E.g. this fails:

```
groovy:000> a*.CRQ1*.status.size()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: CRQ1 for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

So i *guess* you want a list of maps:

```
groovy:000> a = [[CRQ1:[STATUS: "Scheduled"]], [CRQ1:[STATUS: "Draft"]]]
===> [[CRQ1:[STATUS:Scheduled]], [CRQ1:[STATUS:Draft]]]
groovy:000> a.CRQ1.STATUS.size()
===> 2
```